# How to push loop items into an array in VueJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, vue.js

I am using VueJS in my html template and I am trying to loop through a multidimensional array and push certain values into a separate array using VueJS.
Below is my html code:

```
<span v-for="item in details" >
    {{item[0]}}
</span>
```

```js
var app = new Vue ({
 el: "#app",
 data(){
  return {
   column: '',
   details: '',
   email: []
  }
 }
```

Below is the result:

```
EB0010 NA AAM0003 AAM0001 AAM0004 AAM0005 VF0036
```

How can I push these above values into the email array object which I can send in an Axios Post request to a backend API? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Here's my multidimensional array

```
 "DATA":[["AAM0001","March, 07 2016 00:00:00 +0100","Jack","jack@yahoo.com","DMD","Senior Associate","1100000538"],
["AAM0002","March, 10 2016 00:00:00 +0100","Peace","peace@yahoo.com","DMD","Junior Associate","1100000539"]]
```

So I'm trying to push the first and FOURTH items into the email array..

Comment: Where is your multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what exactly is given and what you're trying to achieve, which result is expected etc...

Comment: Couldn't you flatMap the multidimensional array and then just filter the resulting array to whatever you need to match against? @PhilipFeldmann is right we need more examples of what you're trying to achieve in order to help you best.

Comment: @MohammadUsman i have edited my question to include the array.

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann i have edited my question to include the array.

Comment: @Kingsley But your third item is a date-time string. I don't see it in your output array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pull data from your view; you need to do the value selection in your viewmodel. It looks like what you want is a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) like:

```
firstItems() {
  return this.details.map((item) => item[0]);
}
```

You can use that computed in your Axios request as if it were a `data` item.

Comment: Thanks so much @Roy J .. This was exactly what I wanted..